# Unity collision check with disabled colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, polygon, collision, collider

I have in my scene:

1. A GameObject (Layer: Default) with a PolygonCollider2D that:

   - is disabled
   - is not a trigger
2. A player (Layer: Player) that has (all enabled)

   - A PolygonCollider2D
   - A Rigidbody2D

My question:
Is it possible to check if the player is (partly) in the first PolygonCollider2D without enabling it?

Comment: Yes, you can use the bounds of the collider and check if the object is within the bounds: https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+bounds+2d

Comment: Is there a reason you're disabling the whole gameObject including the collider?

Comment: This seems an odd question. Why would you want this. If you want to not show the object. You can disable the renderer

Comment: @Absinthe I already tried this with the intersect method, but that did not work for me.

Comment: @ErikOverflow To keep it short: The disabled GameObject is a potential building that is 'built' (enabled) randomly. But i want to avoid the building if the player is in range of it. I tried to solve the problem with a further collider that is a trigger, but that is very laborious in my context.

Comment: So you want to avoid "enabling" the building if the player is within its range/overlapping with its collider? There's a few ways to do this :)

Comment: I'm assuming you have a "BuildingManager" script that is enabling these buildings. Can you share some of that code in your original post so that we can tailor an answer closer to what you have, rather than giving you 100 different strategies?

Comment: Use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Contains.html with the players `transform.position` as the `point`. You can either use the colliders bounds or just construct a bounds object even without the collider. When you say a suggestion doesn't work it's a good idea to explain why so we can help you further!